# My Custom Dropdownlist does not have a value for Selected Index on submit

Tags: c#, jquery, drop-down-menu, custom-controls

I'm creating a custom Dropdownlist in C# that will look nicer.  I'm writing out a "**ul**" with each item as an "**li**" and having jQuery detect the click and update the actual select, which I render with a class that hides it.  I don't know what I'm doing wrong, obviously.  The custom control inherits from DropDownList

**C# Render Method**

```
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {            
        EnsureChildControls();

        writer.WriteLine("<div class='fs_dropdownlist'>");

        writer.WriteLine("<label>" + this.SelectedItem.Text + "</label>");

        writer.WriteLine("<ul>");
        foreach (ListItem item in this.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
                writer.WriteLine("<li class='selected'>" + item.Text + "</li>");
            else
                writer.WriteLine("<li>" + item.Text + "</li>");
        }
        writer.WriteLine("</ul>");

        writer.WriteLine("<div class='hidden'>");
        base.Render(writer);
        writer.WriteLine("</div>");

        writer.WriteLine("</div>");
    }
```

**jQuery click function**

```
$(".fs_dropdownlist li").on("click", function () {
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    var selectedText = $(this).text();
    var div = $(this).closest(".fs_dropdownlist");
    var ddl = div.find("select");        
    var lbl = div.find("label");

    lbl.text(selectedText);
    ddl.val(selectedText); /* Try to set the value on the select tag */
});
```

So, the issue is the the **SelectedIndex** property of the DropDownList is always -1.  What am I missing?

**NOTE**

I just discovered it doesn't seem to have any items on Postback.

Comment: I guess you have to set the `SelectedIndex` in `foreach (ListItem item in this.Items) ...` . Since Javascript changes the selection on the client side, this information is probably not passed on to the server.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem seems to be that I was populating the items on Render.  This was actually a Time Selector DropDownList, and I made the mistake of populating on Render.  I moved the Population to the CreateChildControls() method, and it's working now.